# How we can change the priority of a process with top command in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to change the priority of a process using top command

Comment: perhaps you meant htop? top and htop are two different tools and htop can indeed change priorities

Answer (score 3):

Once given `top` command, press `r`.
Give PID value of the process you want to change the process value.
Give `renice` value (from -20 to +19)

Nice value of -20 means highest priority value and +19 means lowest priority value. 0 is by default value.

Don't confuse renice value (-20 to +19) with process value (0 to 39)

relation between nice value and priority is :

```
PR = NI + 20
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to erTugRul’s answer, the [`renice`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/renice) command exists for this exact function.

```
renice -5 -p 1234
```